# JMeter jp@gc - HtmlUnit Driver Config

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I would like to know how to run `jp@gc` - WebDriver Sampler using `jp@gc - HtmlUnit Driver Config` in `JMeter`.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

**Get Error Message:**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-06-29 16:49:13 IST
Load time: 7
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1705
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1705
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.sslcontext
Build info: version: '2.47.0', revision: '0e4837e94b1fad0db93e88cd972ed3e235a22892', time: '2015-07-29 15:58:41'
System info: host: 'zconl-37', ip: '10.235.4.31', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
```

Response headers:
SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into `Build info: version: '2.47.0'` line it appears you are using something very outdated, I cannot reproduce your issue using the latest software

[image: JMeter HtmlUnit Demo]

So my recommendations are:

1. Install [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) (or whatever latest version will be available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Install `Selenium/WebDriver Support` bundle using the JMeter Plugins Manager

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager WebDriver Set Installation]
4. Once done you should be able to use WebDriver plugins without any .jar versions clashes.

Comment: Hi, I make the changes as per the above solution but now I got another error.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1745/) concerning wrong HttpComponent jar.

You can check HttpComponent location, it should be version 4.5.1, not earlier:

```
System.out.println(HttpClientBuilder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```